# wfs server with geotools and eg jetty

Tags: jetty, geotools

I would like impelement WFS SERVER using geotools and eg. jetty. Jetty will provide web container and geotools should parse whf requests (getcapabilities etc) and generate resposses (gml, json?) but I am unable to find any solutions. Geotools can works as wsf client but can as server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) which is implemented using [GeoTools](http://geotools.org). Please see my answer to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/why-do-we-need-mapserver-geoserver-to-present-data-from-spatial-database-to-web) as to why starting to write your own WFS is a bad idea :-)

If you really must spend the time and effort to reinvent the wheel then GeoTools is fine - you will want to make use of a [DataStore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/index.html) to read your data in and look at the [XML output modules](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/xsd/index.html) to write out your responses. Don't forget to check the [WFS specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) to make sure you're compliant.

Comment: I do not need whole geoserver, I have to only to generate responses for "GetCapabilities". "GetFutures", "DescribeFeatureType".. requests.

Comment: that is the whole of GeoServer

Comment: But do I have to use biiig geoserver if I want to return list of points?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/why-do-we-need-mapserver-geoserver-to-present-data-from-spatial-database-to-web/15619#15619